# Database schema suggestion

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have three fields in table `user`, where upto three locations for a user are saved. The schema of table is like:

```
UserID, name, location_1, location_2, location_3
```

Now the question is I also have to save user favorite location, so there are two ways.

Either I add another column (in table `user`), named `favorite_location` which will be value of one of the three saved locations.

OR

should I only store the position of location (in column favorite_location), i.e. 2 means `location_2` is currently a favorite location.

**UPDATE:**

I have a limitation to not create another table *UserLocation*

Comment: if you do not want create another table, you can add a FavoriteLocation column to "user" table, that contains name of the location.

Comment: How about having "fav_location", "location_1", "location_2" columns. If "fav_location" is mandatory only these 3 columns will be suffice. If not, add another bit column "IsFavoriteDefined".

Comment: If the sequence is not important, then you can have three columns like this : location_1, location_2 and location_3. Then, enter the favorite location in location_1 and other two location in location_2 and location_3 respectively. This way, you dont need to add either a new table or a new column.

Answer (score 0):

Either way, you are going to create `favorite_location` column. So it's your choice to store complete location value or just the column index.